# Authenticate on Application Insights REST API with AAD

Tags: rest, api, authentication, azure-application-insights

So far I used successfully Application Insights REST API for getting metrics with X-Api-Key header. 
https://api.applicationinsights.io/beta/apps/xxxxxxxxxx/metrics/customMetrics%2FmetricName?timespan=PT2H&interval=PT20M&aggregation=min

However with our new dashboard, crawling several metrics, we hit hard the 1500 request/api key limit.

Some suggest to play around with several api keys, but I would like to prevent this approach.

According to documentation, authenticate with AAD would remove the daily cap (https://dev.applicationinsights.io/documentation/Authorization/Rate-limits)

But I fail to authenticate with AAD (in nodejs, but I suspect it's the same in any language)

I used `adal-node` with a simple app, I successfully get a token, however I'm not able to forward it to the `Request`

```
var context = new AuthenticationContext(authorityUrl);

context.acquireTokenWithClientCredentials(resource, clientId, clientSecret, function(err, tokenResponse) {
  if (err) {
    console.log('well that didn\'t work: ' + err.stack);
  } else {
    console.log(tokenResponse);

    request({'url' : 'https://api.applicationinsights.io/beta/apps/xxxxxxxxx/metrics/customMetrics%2Fmetrics?timespan=PT2H&interval=PT20M&aggregation=min',
    headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + tokenResponse.accessToken
        }
    }, function (error,response,body){
            console.log(body);
    });
  }
});
```

[image]

I'm getting following error message
`The provided authentication is not valid for this resource`
`The given API Key is not valid for the requested resource`

I suspect I miss something :)

Comment: Hi did you find any solution for this ?

Comment: Not for the present time, I'm little perplex on how using the powershell commands (see below answer) described in the documentation. For the time being I'm cheating with a set of apikeys :(

Comment: I've ending up using Azure Log Analytics queries targeting several metrics at once in order to address the limit issue. https://dev.applicationinsights.io/apiexplorer/postQuery

Answer (score 3):

We don't support AAD in our REST API directly. Your resource is managed by the Azure Resource Manager, and only it can validate a certain user has access to this resource. API Keys are our way of short circuiting the authorization directly to a resource, instead of in the user context.

You gave this AAD app access to this resource as yourself, so the authentication is still in the context of a user. The call has to be made to ARM instead: 'https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/xxxxxx/resourcegroups/xxxxx/providers/microsoft.insights/components/xxxxx/api/metrics/customMetrics%2Fmetrics?api-version=2014-12-01-preview&timespan=PT2H&interval=PT20M&aggregation=min'

Documentation is linked here - though not explained explicitly: https://dev.applicationinsights.io/documentation/Authorization

This will get you a higher rate-limit, and still return the same response as the REST API.

Comment: Ah ! I've totally missed this documentation page (I thought it was only a section header ...) But I knew I was missing out something! I will give a try asap.

Comment: The documentation make reference to Connect-ARM & Execute-ARMQuery which from my understanding is coming from here (https://github.com/dushyantgill/AzureResourceManagerPowerShell) and not maintained since 2 years. Is it correct ?