# How to perform queries using the Azure API format: user authentication

Tags: node.js, azure, active-directory, azure-application-insights

I want to get json data as explain in rest api doc https://dev.applicationinsights.io/documentation/overview

```
customEvents | where customDimensions.teamId == '8bcb0466-8227-4de4-b001-b70381b9cd04'
```

As the rest api have limit of 15 call per min and 1500 per day as doc https://dev.applicationinsights.io/documentation/Authorization/Rate-limits says to use Azure API and Azure Active Directory but there is no example available for that.

I want to do it in node js but didn't find any sdk for the same.

For AD authentication I used assport-azure-ad library.

Comment: The similar thread can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42978366/authenticate-on-application-insights-rest-api-with-aad. About how to use AAD authentication you can refer to [this guide](http://www.dushyantgill.com/blog/2015/05/23/developers-guide-to-auth-with-azure-resource-manager-api/).

Comment: guide link is not working, it says : Error establishing a database connection

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Authenticate on Application Insights REST API with AAD](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42978366/authenticate-on-application-insights-rest-api-with-aad)